# How to decode the result of javascript code execution

Tags: javascript, json, encoding, ascii

```
str='@3C@69@66@72@61@6D@65@20@61@6C@6C@6F@77@74@72@61@6E@73@70@61@72@65@6E@63@79@3D@22@31@22@20@66@72@61@6D@65@62@6F@72@64@65@72@3D@22@30@22@20@68@65@69@67@68@74@3D@22@33@30@38@22@20@69@64@3D@22@70@6C@77@70@72@31@33@33@38@30@35@33@31@36@33@32@34@62@63@38@39@34@36@35@2E@34@33@38@39@39@34@33@37@22@20@73@63@72@6F@6C@6C@69@6E@67@3D@22@6E@6F@22@20@73@72@63@3D@22@68@74@74@70@3A@2F@2F@6F@77@2E@6C@79@2F@41@6D@6B@64@33@30@32@50@41@47@47@22@20@77@69@64@74@68@3D@22@34@38@36@22@3E@3C@2F@69@66@72@61@6D@65@3E';
document.write(unescape(str.replace(/@/g,'%')));
```

Comment: Try doing what it does manually.  First, replace `@` with `%`.  Most simple text editors have a search-and-replace option you can use to do this.  Then, unescape the string, by turning every `%xx` string into the equivalent Unicode character; for example, `%2F` is "character 47", or `/`.  You can use search-and-replace for this, too, by holding alt and entering the number on the numeric keypad (this is easy if you've [enabled Unicode hex altcodes](http://superuser.com/questions/13086/how-do-you-type-unicode-characters-using-hexadecimal-codes), just enter the hex code that way).

Answer (score 1):

This is not a json related problem, but a string encoded in hexa ascii code.

Here is a python2 code to "see" this string :

```
s='@3C@69@66@72@61@6D@65@20@61@6C@6C@6F@77@74@72@61@6E@73@70@61@72@65@6E@63@79@3D@22@31@22@20@66@72@61@6D@65@62@6F@72@64@65@72@3D@22@30@22@20@68@65@69@67@68@74@3D@22@33@30@38@22@20@69@64@3D@22@70@6C@77@70@72@31@33@33@38@30@35@33@31@36@33@32@34@62@63@38@39@34@36@35@2E@34@33@38@39@39@34@33@37@22@20@73@63@72@6F@6C@6C@69@6E@67@3D@22@6E@6F@22@20@73@72@63@3D@22@68@74@74@70@3A@2F@2F@6F@77@2E@6C@79@2F@41@6D@6B@64@33@30@32@50@41@47@47@22@20@77@69@64@74@68@3D@22@34@38@36@22@3E@3C@2F@69@66@72@61@6D@65@3E'
print ''.join([x.decode('hex') for x in s.split('@')[1:]])
```

and the result :

> ```
> <iframe allowtransparency="1" frameborder="0" height="308" id="plwpr133805316324bc89465.43899437" scrolling="no" src="..." width="486"></iframe>
> ```